# arcore, placing 3D model without the touch with unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

[image]

I'm making an AR application using ARCore and Unity.

I wanted to place 3D models on vertical walls without touch.

It is almost implemented, but when creating a 3D model, it Keeps going to the left down.

I think it's because I've set the anchor position

```c#
Vector3 position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

But if I changed the anchor position to

```c#
 Vector3 position = new Vector3 (hit.Pose.position.x, hit.Pose.position.y, hit.Pose.position.z)
```

It doesn't go to the center too.

Does anyone know how to put a 3D object in the middle of the plane?

```c#
TrackableHit hit;     
TrackableHitFlags raycastFilter = TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon |
TrackableHitFlags.FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal;


if (Frame.Raycast(transform.position.x,transform.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
{
    if (CurrentNumberOfGameObjects < numberOfGameObjectsAllowed)
        {
            Destroy(ARObject);

        if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) 
             && Vector3.Dot(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
        }
        else
        {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

            ARObject = Instantiate(ARAndroidPrefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);                                                  
            ARObject.transform.Rotate(-90, 0, 0, Space.Self);
            var anchor = Session.CreateAnchor(new Pose(position, rotation));
            ARObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
                CurrentNumberOfGameObjects = CurrentNumberOfGameObjects + 1;

                // Hide Plane once ARObject is Instantiated 
                foreach (GameObject Temp in DetectedPlaneGenerator.instance.PLANES) //RK
                {
                    Temp.SetActive(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just some general notes: instead of `new Vector3(0,0,0)` you could/should use `Vector3.zero`; instead of `new Quaternion(0,0,0,1)` use `Quaternion.Identity`; `ARObject.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0, Space.Self);` does absolutely nothing .. you probably ment `ARObject.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Identity;`

Comment: @derHugo thaks for the comment, I modified it as you wrote it. And the rotate part is my mistake. it should be (-90,0,0).

Comment: did you try to create the anchor first and then do `Instantiate(ARAndroidPrefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation, anchor.transform)`?

Comment: I also feel like there is a `}` missing somewhere ;)

Comment: i've tried just now,  but it went in the left downwards and in the inside of the z-axis.

Answer (score 0):

i changed code

```
Vector3 position = Vector3.zero; // Vector3 position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

to

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.position.x, Camera.main.transform.position.y , hit.Pose.position.z);
```

and then it works.